# What is the default action of 'a' tag?

Tags: javascript, html

When I see [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), I found the defination is

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent that if the event goes unhandled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

The key word is :`its default action should not be taken as it normally would be`.

When it comes to `a` tag, I want to know **the full set of default actions of an `a` element**, not just `click`.

`<a href="https://www.google.com/">Go to Google</a>`

When I click this text `Go to Google`, I'll go to Google's homepage.

I had looked at [HTML5 specification - the-a-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), did not found an answer.

Comment: _"When I click this text `Go to Google`, I'll go to Google's homepage"_ --- this is the default action of an `a` element.

Comment: Did you not read [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)? --- _"The activation behavior of a elements that create hyperlinks is to run the following steps"_...

Comment: ＠evolutionxbox, yes. I know when I click it , it may be  the default action of an `a` element. But how about `touchend`? Are there any default action of `a` element **when `touchend`**? I want to know all default actions about `a` element.

Comment: the default action is the redirect, so in your link, preventDefault would stop the redirect

Comment: Clearly, each event potentially has a default action. It may even have different default actions depending on context. You should clarify your question to make it clear that you are looking for the full set of default actions of an `a` element and not as it reads at the moment, like you are looking for a single default action, which would typically imply that of the click event.

Comment: @Alohci Can you give me a link where I can find all the default actions about `a` element? Thank you.

Comment: No. You will need to read in multiple places, where the events are defined. For example, the touchend default action can be found in the [touch-events spec](https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#click-events)

Comment: @Alohci Thank you very much for your link.

Answer (score 2):

The default action of a Hyperlink `<a>` lies within the `href` tag attribute. If the value of the `href` attribute is an external link (e.g. https://google.com) , the default action is; navigate to `https://google.com` link. If the specified `href` value is an internal link(i.e. ID of an element) then the default action is; move the scroll position to the **top position of the element**. One last thing, if the value is an internal link and the element ID doesn't exist, then, the default action is scroll to the **top of the page**.

Then, calling the `preventDefault()` method prevents the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks. But how about `touchend`? Are there any default action of `a ` element **when `touchend`**? I want to know **all default actions** about `a` element.

Comment: The default action of the Hyperlink doesn't change from device-to-device, it stays the same across devices. Whether It'd be mouse pointer, or touch-oriented devices.

Comment: I know it doesn't change from device-to-device. But, are you sure `a` element has **ONLY** one default action? Do you have any docs about it?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that `<a>` has only one action, **default action** is in singular form, as stated in the specifications.

Comment: Thank you, @Den isahac. This link is [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), right?

Comment: You can also use that link as a reference for your research. And also this one; [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147613/discussion-between-den-isahac-and-zhongyuan-zhou).

Answer (score -3):

Tag `<a>` has been created as hyperlink. You can wrap the majority of elements, like text and images, inside an `<a>` tag.

The simple message you wrote like

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Go to Google</a>
```

You can change it a little bit and you will have

```
<a href="https://youtube.com/">YOUTUBE</a>
```

And always you can add "target=_blank". It means that you will be redirected to new card in for example Chrome.

Example:

```
<a href="https://youtube.com/" target="_blank">YOUTUBE</a>
```

Comment: this is answering a different question of `what does the <a> tag do?` - the OP would like to know what `preventDefault` does to the `<a>` tag